# In nodejs collection.find() is not fetching values from Mongodb collection.It returning nothing

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb

```js
app.get('/render', function(req, res) {
  MongoClient.connect(dburl, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var collection = db.collection('shopping_list');
  collection.find().toArray(function(err, result) {
    
    res.send({result :result});
  
  });
  db.close();
});
});
```

In nodejs collection.find() is not fetching values from Mongodb collection.It returning nothing
In nodejs collection.find() is not fetching values from Mongodb collection.It returning nothing

Comment: `toArray()` is not needed instead use `.exec(function(err,result){})` because find always returns a array of objects from `mongodb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
var queryObj = {};
UserModel.find(queryObj)
.exec(function(err, users) {
    if (!users) {
        console.log("users not found");
    }
    if (!err) {
        console.log("number of users",users.length);
    } else {
        console.log("err",err);
    }
});
```

};